# Any guide please, operator theory

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Lat $X,Y$ be banach spaces and $T:X\to Y$ a function.
Assume that there is a function $S:Y^*\to X^*$ such that for all $x\in X, y^*\in Y^*$  , $y^*(Tx)=(Sy^*)(x)$.
Prove that $T\in B(X,Y)$ (that means $T:X\to Y$ is linear and bounded).

I have a problem with this question since i need to show that T is linear and bounded however I did nof understand how to use the information given about S!
Can you please clarify it to me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $$y^*(T(x + y)) = (Sy^*)(x + y) = (Sy^*)(x)  +(Sy^*)(y) = y^*(Tx) + y^*(Ty) = y^*(Tx + Ty).$$ Since $y^* \in Y^*$ is arbitrary, it follows that the arguments are equal (by Hahn-Banach theorem). Something similar holds for scalar multiplication.

If $x_n \to 0$ and $Tx_n \to y$, then $y^*(Tx_n) \to y^*(y)$ and $(Sy^*)(x_n) \to (Sy^*)(0) = 0$, since $Sy^* \in X^*$. It follows that $y = 0$, hence $T$ is bounded by the closed graph theorem.

Comment: I am using that - if two points are different - then there is a linear functional that can tell them apart. If $x,y \in X$ are distinct, we can consider two cases. If $x \in \mathrm{span} (y)$ then we simply take $\phi \in X^*$ such that $\phi(y) = 1$. Then, $\phi(x) = \phi(cy) = c \phi(y) =  c \neq 1$, since $x \neq y$. Otherwise, one can define a functional $\psi \in X^*$ that is zero on $\mathrm{span}(y)$ and 1 on $x$. In both cases, the existence follows directly from the Hahn,Banach theorem.